# How can you sync a calender with an iCal link?

Tags: sync, calendar

The school that I am going to has a calender that you can sync to other devices and programs through an iCal feed. There is just a link, no account info or anything. Is it possible to sync the events to the S Planner with this link? If not, is there another free solution out there?

Answer (score 7):

For read only feeds [ICSDroid](https://icsdroid.bitfire.at/) does this. It'll work with facebook's feeds too.

[DavDroid](https://davdroid.bitfire.at/) will do the same for a proper caldav server (syncs in both directions)

Comment: Indeed!  They're both on [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/) for those of us trying to avoid the Google Play store, and the code is available on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/), which is also open source (GitHub, but better).

Comment: The ICSDroid link is dead, and trying to download from F-Droid fails.

Comment: The apps are now known as [ICSx⁵](https://icsx5.bitfire.at/) and [DAVx⁵](https://www.davx5.com/); both are on F-Droid ([ICSx⁵](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/at.bitfire.icsdroid/), [DAVx⁵](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/at.bitfire.davdroid/)) and Google Play. Should work with any calendar app; I can confirm ICSx⁵ works great with the /e/ calendar app (a fork of [Etar](https://f-droid.org/packages/ws.xsoh.etar/)).

Answer (score 4):

I think what you need to do is subscribe to your calendar in Google Calendar, then have your calendar app sync with this feed--much like you would sync additional calenders like days of the week, etc.

[Subscribe to public calendars using the calendar address](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37100?hl=en)

1. Click the down-arrow next to Other calendars
2. Select Add by URL from the menu
3. Find the address of the Google Calendar in iCalendar format, or if you have the iCalendar address of a calendar from a different application (for example, Apple's iCal), you can use this as well.
4. Enter the address in the field provided
5. Click the Add Calendar button. The calendar will appear in the Other Calendars section of the calendar list to the left.

Then, in the Calendar app, or S Planner, on your phone choose the additional calendars to display.

Comment: It's terrible that you still cannot do this from the app. I filed a request here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/FNo0ZP9F-tU;context-place=forum/calendar

Comment: About how to perform the last step (choosing the additional calendars to display): I found that it was necessary (on my Android device) to go to Calendar -> Menu bar -> Settings -> Show more -> <select the desired calendar> and toggle the "Sync" setting. After performing this step, the desired calendar appeared among those listed in the calendar app's main menu bar.

Comment: @Jasha thanks, that was the point I was missing!